# How can I make the Window change it's position on Screen of a mac with pure SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a pure SwiftUI code for changing the position of Window in macOS SwiftUI? I know there is a way via AppKit codes and using `NSApp.mainWindow` and then using `window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true`, but my approach is not about that way, I want to know if there is an approach using SwiftUI modifiers like offset or position or any other SwiftUI modifier to reach the goal?

This is my current code, it does not move Window:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .background(Color.purple)
        .offset(offset)
        .gesture(gesture)
    }
    
    var gesture: some Gesture {
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { dragValue in
                offset = CGSize(width: dragValue.translation.width, height: -dragValue.translation.height)
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                offset = .zero
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIKit` has no `NSApp.mainWindow`

Comment: As far as I know there isn’t, you need to use AppKit for this.